# Is 'haven't a clue' slang? and do people all over the world use it or is it just a British thing, or is it used by a smaller group of people?

Tags: phrases, slang, colloquial-language

Just wondering as I always use it and people often ask me what I'm talking about. So it got me thinking that it might just be a British thing, or maybe even just a thing people from the country commonly use? I'm use to people questioning phrases I commonly use, as I was brought up using cockney rhyming slang and half the time I don't even realise that nobody understands what I am on about. But I didn't think 'haven't a clue' was a cockney thing? or maybe I am just overthinking and everybody uses it?

EDIT: I know cockney isn't from the country. Half my family are Londoners and the other half are country.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly a common expression. "I haven't a clue" is a slightly abbreviated form of "I have not got a clue". Said in response to a question you do not know the answer to, it literally means that, not only do you not know the answer but neither do you know anything which might act as a clue towards the correct answer.

It might well be considered an *idiom*, although strictly speaking, an expression is an "idiom" when its meaning as an expression cannot be determined by analysing the individual words alone. The meaning seems pretty straightforward to me.

I wouldn't really think of it as *slang* either for the same reason - it isn't replacement language - although as you point out, in some 'cockney' London accents (and probably others too) it is heavily abbreviated, dropping the "I" and simply saying "haven't a clue". That could fit the definition of slang as "*words and phrases that are regarded as **very informal**, are **more common in speech than writing**, and are typically restricted to a particular context or group of people*".

Shortening it that way might be typically British English, but as an expression it isn't restricted to the UK. US English speakers may favour the word "clueless" (the title of a 1995 US movie), or the similar "I don't have a clue" (the title of a book by US author Sarah Cortez), which again go to proving that "haven't a clue" isn't strictly an idiom because it's meaning is tied to its component words and can mean the same formatted differently.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no slang here; “clue” has its normal dictionary meaning. But the verb has an important caveat:

> I haven’t a clue.

This sounds somewhat BrE to my AmE ears. I know what it means, but I’d say:

> I don’t have a clue.

AmE doesn’t allow contracting “have” as a main verb, so we add auxiliary “do” and contract that instead. The meaning is the same.